# Linux Socket Bad File Descriptor

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I couldn’t find a duplicate, so I decided to post. We're getting into Sockets (beginner-level) now, and was given the code below to make the client send a simple message to the server by using `send()` and `recv()`. However, everything I have tried doesn’t seem to get rid of the `error: Bad File Descriptor` and `newsockfd` always returns the value `-1`. I'm confused and have no idea why it doesn’t work.

**defs.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define SERV_TCP_PORT 6000
#define SERV_HOST_ADDR  "127.0.0.1" 

char *pname;
```

**client.c**

```
#include "../defs.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

  pname=argv[0];
  bzero((char*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(SERV_HOST_ADDR);
  serv_addr.sin_port=htons(SERV_TCP_PORT);
  if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0) {
    printf("client: can't open stream socket\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    printf("client: can't connect to server\n");
    exit(0);
  }
 send(sockfd,"1",1,0);
  close(sockfd);
  exit(0);
}
```

**server.c**

```
#include "../defs.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <strings.h>
void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}
main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
  int sockfd,clilen, childpid;
 int newsockfd;
char buff[255];
  struct sockaddr_in cli_addr, serv_addr;
  if ((sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0)) <0) {
    printf("server: can't open stream socket\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  bzero((char*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  serv_addr.sin_port=htons(SERV_TCP_PORT);

  if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    printf("server: can't bind local address\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  listen(sockfd, 5);
  for ( ; ; ) {
    clilen=sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
  printf("%d\n",newsockfd);
    if(newsockfd < 0) {
      printf("server: accept error\n");
    error("ERROR on accept");
      exit(0);
    }
    if((childpid=fork()) <0) {
      printf("server: fork error\n");
      exit(0);
    }
    else if (childpid==0) {
        close(sockfd);  
      recv(newsockfd,buff,sizeof(buff),0);
    }
    close(newsockfd);
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The first thing to do is to print out more details about the error. In Linux, the last error is stored in the "errno" value. Print that out and look up what the value means. Or use the "perror" function to print out a string message corresponding to the error.

Comment: The perror function was returning ERROR on accept, Bad File Descriptor, but Corluk explained my error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code of the child you **close** `sockfd`, which represents the server. But in the next iteration of the infinite for-loop, **which the child also runs**, you attempt to `accept()` a new client **using** `sockfd`. Therefore, `sockfd` is a `Bad file descriptor`.

Remove the `close(sockfd);` line in your code and close it when you can be absolutely sure it is not needed anymore.